# Backing up MBR - why not restoring the boot code?

Tags: partitioning, backup, mbr, dd

I've seen two pages explaining how to backup & restore the [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_Boot_Record):

- [Linux: How to backup hard disk partition table (MBR)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-backup-hard-disk-partition-table-mbr.html)
- [UNIX / Linux: Copy Master Boot Record (MBR)](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-copy-mbr/)

They've shown an example with restoring only the partition table (64 bytes):

```
dd if= sda-mbr.bin of=/dev/sdX bs=1 count=64 skip=446 seek=446
```

And an example with restoring the entire MBR (512 bytes):

```
dd if=backup-sda.mbr of=/dev/sda
```

What's the reason one wouldn't want to restore the boot code (the first 446 bytes)?

Comment: Hypothesis 1: Disks are mounted in a different way, the boot code stops being valid.
Hypothesis 2: There is already a boot code and someone doesn't want to override the code that already exists.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard: Ain't restoring the entire 512 bytes be the most common scenario?

Comment: I actually don't know, because I never did it, although I find the question interesting.